# Configure a group of type registrations at one time

Tags: c#, autofac

In my code, currently types are registered with lots of duplicated code, e.g.

```
builder.RegisterType<UserViewModelValidation>()
    .As<IValidator<UserViewModel>>()
    .PropertiesAutowired().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.RegisterType<RoleValidation>()
    .As<IValidator<Role>>()
    .PropertiesAutowired().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Instead of having to configure each of these registrations one by one, is there a way to configure a group of them?

So in the above code, it's specifically the `PropertiesAutowired()` function and `InstancePerLifetimeScope()` function which is generic to a group of type registrations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom extension method that will do what you want.

```
public static class RegistrationExtensions
{
    public static IRegistrationBuilder<TValidator, ConcreteReflectionActivatorData, SingleRegistrationStyle> 
        RegisterValidator<TValidator, TViewModel>(this ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.RegisterType<TValidator>()
                      .As<IValidator<TViewModel>>()
                      .PropertiesAutowired()
                      .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }
}
```

And then register your type like this :

```
builder.RegisterValidator<UserViewModelValidation, UserViewModel>();
builder.RegisterValidator<RoleValidation, Role>();
```

Comment: This completes my life. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Cyril's answer, I created some additional extensions for registering types in my application using Autofac.

```
public static IRegistrationBuilder<T, ConcreteReflectionActivatorData, SingleRegistrationStyle>
    RegisterInstance<T, TServiceType>(this ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    return builder.RegisterType<T>().As<TServiceType>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
}

public static IRegistrationBuilder<T, ConcreteReflectionActivatorData, SingleRegistrationStyle>
    RegisterAutowiredInstance<T>(this ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    return builder.RegisterType<T>().PropertiesAutowired().InstancePerRequest();
}

public static IRegistrationBuilder<object, ReflectionActivatorData, DynamicRegistrationStyle>
    RegisterGenericInstance(this ContainerBuilder builder, Type type, Type serviceType)
{
    return builder.RegisterGeneric(type).As(serviceType).InstancePerRequest();
}
```

Usage examples:

```
builder.RegisterInstance<UnitOfWork, IUnitOfWork>();
builder.RegisterAutowiredInstance<Authorize>();
builder.RegisterGenericInstance(typeof(EntityBaseRepository<>), typeof(IEntityBaseRepository<>));
```

Helps to reduce the amount of redundant code and typing when registering new types.